# Not sure how to work out SSG and SSE in ANOVA table

Tags: regression

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Not sure how to work out SSG and SSE on ANOVA table](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/39134/not-sure-how-to-work-out-ssg-and-sse-on-anova-table)

I have a table that is:

$$
\begin{matrix} & \mathrm{Tyre\, A} & \mathrm{Tyre\, B} & \mathrm{Tyre\, C} & \mathrm{Total} \\ \mathrm{number\, of\, tyres\, tested} & 25 & 32 & 40 & 97 \\ \mathrm{mean\, response*} & 18.46 & 19.56 & 16.47 & 18.00 \\ \mathrm{sample\, variance**} & 14.42 & 13.66 & 26.77 & 20.73 \end{matrix} 
$$

*mean was calculated as $bar{y} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i$.
**variance was calculated as $ \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} (y_i - \bar{y})^2 $

Using this information, I need to create an ANOVA table. The degrees of freedom were easy (I got 2, 94 and 96). But I am now stuck on the SS columns of the table. For SST I did:

$(N - 1)S_T^2 $ and used 20.73 as the total variance and this gave me SST = 1990.08. Is that correct?

Also, I am stuck on how to work out SSG or SSE. I know if I can work one out, then I'll have the other but how do I do this?

Comment: I think you should ask the moderators to move this question to stats.SE.